# If God is just what is the point of life?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, life

Before answering let me just lay out my thoughts so it’s easy for you to understand where I got this from. Also I’m not here to make fun of or insult people or anything.

First and foremost, God knows everything and everything has been predestined our futures are set that’s that.

Secondly, and this is mainly just my interpretation, people who are in dire need of something tend to look towards God.  There have been psychological studies to back the belief that people who are punished/suffer think there will be merit/rewards from going through said trials and this ties into religion too. If you look at the countries in the worst states where they need food, shelter etc they turn to God and have hope however as countries have progressed and advanced there is no longer this need and people have become self sufficient so there is no need to turn to God. It’s safe to assume over a period of time that if these countries were given such a privilege the same outcome would occur and of course with a few exceptions. As time is passing on the decline in faith is rising too and understandably, a lot of religious statements seem mythical and legendary at best and obviously this would lead to disbelief countries who now have the power and technology to interpret this and understand it, look into the universe and philosophy of it have seen a decline in faith.

If assuming God exists God will also know that this was bound to happen, people were bound to disbelieve and it’s a reasonable thing to do. As religious as you are it’s hard to deny that this is reasonable when looking at them they seem like straight out a fairy tale and the existence of God is rooted down to a being beyond time, space, has no physical being etc etc which is the same as something non-existent.

God knew this will happen so why create a fate for certain humans that has set them to eternal suffering for something such as this? How is that just? It would’ve been better if they didn’t exist. What’s the point?

Comment: Because Allah is creator. He creates what he wills. There are no ifs or buts. He just does what he wills.

Comment: So what you’re asking is, “why did god create people if some are just simply destined for hell?”

Answer (score 0):

Allah has granted men and women life, and the ability to choose between good and evil. The point of life is life itself and to find oneself on the best path, the true path. This is what Islam enjoins upon muslims. They are not to retreat from life by cloistering themselves in 'monasteries', but to participate in living.

And Allah Knows best.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is to find our goal in life, our purpose of life, so whoever a poor or a rich both has a purpose of life whether they search for it or not. The word used in arabic for religion is deen which means the way of life. Everyone needs a way of life whether he is rich or poor. Many poor people accept religion because they want happiness and they find happiness whether in religion or religion's reward, so they accept it. Many rich people are happy so they are not attracted by the religion's reward, but still they need a way of life, they are happy doesn't mean they don't need a way of life. They live the way they want to live , but this is their responsibility to find the purpose of their life.